# Insert (not append) new series to chart

Tags: microsoft-excel-2013, charts

I have data in the form of:

```
Date | Created | Complete |  Avg Time (Days)
July |       8 |        2 |              25
Aug  |       2 |        5 |              75
Sept |       1 |        1 |              80
...
```

and have created a hybrid (Column/Line) chart, with the Avg Time shown as a line on the secondary axis.  Data is from July to June.  It looks like this:

[image]

Now, I want to add a second set of data containing info from the previous year, but when I right-click / select data and add the additional cells, the chart ends up as one long line of data.  What I want is to have both sets of 'July' data in the same area - with the two series of 'Created' data and the two series of 'Complete' data partly overlapping, with two (different coloured) lines for the two sets of Average Time. The purpose of this is to enable comparison for the same time in the previous year.  It should look something like (ignore the fact the extra columns don't touch the axis, I just added drawing rectangles):

[image]

I'm sure I could do this fairly easily in Excel 2003.

How do I do this in Excel 2013?

Answer (score 0):

Closest option I've find is using a pivot chart like below:

[image]

This way you can also specify year to drive series names. It's not exactly the same as in your desired picture as years are not separated, however you can customize your colours to indicate which data belongs together.